# Calculate and use inverse of OpenCV distortion parameters

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration, distortion

So basically I want to find out what the invert distortion parameters would be for a calibration I do as showed [here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html).

**NOTE: I know that we can perform undistortion and then use remapping to do what I have done below, but my goal is to be able to find out the actual inverted distortion parameters and use them to distort other images, not to just be able to revert what cv2.undistort() does**

---

**Overview:**

I have tried passing in the negation of the distortion parameters:

```
# _, mat, distortion, _, _ = cv2.calibrateCamera(...)
# undistorted_image = cv2.undistort(with distortion) 
# redistorted_image = cv2.undistort(with np.negative(distortion))
```

In theory, I was thinking that if the redistorted_image is similar to the original image, then the `np.negative(distortion)` parameters are what I am looking for, but it turned out to be false.

---

**Actual method I use:**

```
def save_undistorted_images(image, matrix, distortion):
    test_image_su = cv.imread(image)
    height, width = test_image_su.shape[:2]
    new_camera_mtx, roi = cv.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(matrix, distortion, (width, height), 1, (width, height))

    distortion_u = np.negative(distortion)

    # unsure if this line helps
    new_camera_mtx_inv, roi = cv.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(matrix, distortion_u, (width, height), 1, (width, height))

    # undistort the image
    undistorted_image = cv.undistort(test_image_su, matrix, distortion, None, new_camera_mtx)
    cv.imwrite('undistorted_frame.png', undistorted_image)

    # redistort trying to get something like original image (image_test_su) 
    distorted_image = cv.undistort(undistorted_image, matrix, distortion_u, None, new_camera_mtx_inv)
    cv.imwrite('redistorted_frame.png', distorted_image)
```

The results:

(left **a**: original) (right **b**: undistorted)

[image] [image]

(left **c**: distorted using `np.negative(distortion)`) (right **d**: undistorted image **re**distorted using `np.negative(distortion)`))

[image] [image]

The image d here is basically c performed on b, which I expected would be similar to a

Why is **b** here overpowering the effect of **c**?

---

**Other way of calculating inverse that I tried:**

The following is my python implementation of this [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/315824536_Calculating_the_Inverse_Radial_Distortion_Model_Based_on_Zhang_method)

```
    distortion_u = distortion

    k1 = distortion_u[0][0]
    k2 = distortion_u[0][1]
    k3 = distortion_u[0][4]

    b1 = -1 * k1
    b2 = 3 * (k1 * k1) - k2
    b3 = (8 * k1 * k2) + (-1 * (12 * (k1 * k1 * k1))) - k3
    
    # radial:
    distortion_u[0][0] = b1
    distortion_u[0][1] = b2
    distortion_u[0][4] = b3
   
    # tangential: 
    #distortion_u[0][2] = -1 * distortion_u[0][2]
    #distortion_u[0][3] = -1 * distortion_u[0][3]
```

The results of applying distortion on undistorted image using above distortion parameters is also not good, looks really similar to results above.

---

So, this brings us to:

Why is the effect of normal distortion always overpowering np.negative(distortion) or anything else?

Does all distortion work this way? (negative values does not equal to opposite effect)

How to get the actually opposite distortion parameters?

Answer (score 6):

Afraid you are doing it wrong. The [opencv distortion model](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html) you have calibrated computes undistorted and normalized image coordinates from distorted ones. It is a nonlinear model, so inverting it involves solving a system of nonlinear (polynomial) equations.

A closed form (parametric) solution exists AFAIK only for the case of single-parameter pure radial distortion, i.e. when the only nonzero distortion parameter is k1, the coefficient of r^2. In this case the model inversion equation reduces to a cubic equation in r, and you can then express the inverse model using Cardano's formula for the solution of the cubic.

In all other cases one inverts the model numerically, using various algorithms for solving the nonlinear system of equations. OpenCV uses an iterative "false-position" method.

Since you want to use the inverse model to un-distort a set of images (which is the normal use case), you should use [initUndistortRectifyMap](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga7dfb72c9cf9780a347fbe3d1c47e5d5a) to calculate the undistortion solution for the image once and for all, and then pass it for every image to [remap](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gab75ef31ce5cdfb5c44b6da5f3b908ea4) to actually undistort the images.

If you ***really*** need a parametric model for the inverse model, my advice would be to look into approximating the maps returned by initUndistortRectifyMap with a pair of higher order polynomials, or thin-plate splines.

Comment: This is helpful. I think, what undistort does is basically call initUndistortRectifyMap() and then remap(), so replacing undistort with manual calls to these two is the same. Also, I do not get why applying undistortion solution for an image to other images is going to help. Also, would you happen to know any papers published or threads about what you mentioned in the last paragraph.

Comment: It's the same result-wise, but computing initUndistorRectifyMap is expensive time-wise. If the same calibration applies to a bunch of images, computing it only once is more efficient if you care about speed.
You can apply the undistortion solution to images subsequently captured with the same camera, provided the lens hasn't been touched (moved with respect to the sensor, refocused, etc.)
As far as approximating the undistortion maps with a parametric model, it's a vast topic.  Look for reference on interpolation on a grid. Note that the choice of method will depend a lot on the intended use