# Fast Implementation of the 1 Parameter Division Distortion Model

Tags: python, numpy, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I have implemented some code that allows me to estimate the center of distortion for an image along with a distortion parameter that attempts to remove any radial distortion present in the image. It is modelled after the [one-parameter division model by Fitzgibbon](https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/%7Evgg/publications/2001/Fitzgibbon01b/fitzgibbon01b.pdf):

`xu = xd / (1 + K1 * r^2)`

`yu = yd / (1 + K1 * r^2)`

I am wondering what the best way is to process this transform as fast as possible. I was thinking there should be a way to use numpy vectorization to create a mapping for a given image that I can use to perform the undistortion procedure. I have experience with OpenCV (undistort(), initUndistortRectifyMap(), etc.), however, these methods require an estimate of the camera focal properties (`fx, fy`) which I do not have.

I could implement a nested for loop structure to calculate all of the undistorted destinations for a given input image size, however, this would be very inefficient. Is there an approach I can take with numpy to build this mapping?

Here is how I transform a single point from the distorted state to the undistorted state.

```
def get_undistorted(pd, dc, k):
    xd, yd = pd
    dcx, dcy = dc
    r2 = (dcx - xd)**2 + (dcy - yd)**2
    xu = dcx + (xd - dcx)/(1 + k*r2)
    yu = dcy + (yd - dcy)/(1 + k*r2)
    return xu, yu
```

Comment: How would you apply `get_undistorted` to an image?

Comment: Well for an input image that is 320x240 iterating through the (x, y) positions ((0, 0), …, (319, 239)) and applying get_undistorted() to find where the point would map to in the new undistorted image. Then if the undistorted position lies in the 320x240 region, update a new image with the pixels values. Some areas of the undistorted image may be left black. I have gone through a few research papers (https://centaur.reading.ac.uk/69206/1/OE_56_1_013108.pdf) that don’t seem to cover the last step of actually applying the undistortion model so I’m not confident on how to properly apply it.

Comment: For a given set of distortion parameters, is there always one image to undistort? Or do you apply the transform to multiple images?

Comment: I’d like to undistort multiple images. The use case may be for a given recorded video: extract frames, apply undistortion, apply some other processing etc.

Comment: are you asking for `cv::remap()`?

Comment: Perhaps so, though it's unclear whether the Python bindings to OpenCV are available in this context.

Comment: I'm asking OP though, and since OP already mentioned use of OpenCV, and `pip install opencv-python` is trivial on common systems, I don't see a hurdle.

Comment: I had looked at remap but incorrectly assumed it was only related to the output of initUndistortRectifyMap(). So I suppose I could implement the nested approach to build the maps (which would only need to be done once) and then apply remap. Thanks.

Comment: indeed remap() is a general primitive, but with few explicit uses in OpenCV. undistort-rectify maps are one application because they are expensive or impossible to express algebraically. simple affine or perspective warps could be expressed in terms of remap() but the operations themselves are trivial enough to not need LUTs and I don't see an API to do that just now. it's easy to do however. just requires filling one image with indices and then mapping it (perhaps with an inversion of the affine/perspective matrix, I'd have to reason through it)

Comment: I haven't read the paper entirely yet. I think you need to be careful with the equations in that the distortion *factor* using the radius needs to be calculated from the "perfect" point, whereas the equation for undistortion requires division, but also some more thought for the radius calculation. without that, both equations are fine models in their respective directions but their coefficients aren't directly convertible, I don't think.

Comment: eh, that paper seems to play loose with the notations and equations (1) and (2). at least as far as I understand it.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz what do you mean by “…radius needs to be calculated from the "perfect" point…”

Comment: `r^2` shows up in both the distortion equation and the undistortion equation. it's not the same `r`. in one case, it's the r of the undistorted/perfect point. in the other case, it's the r of the distorted point. each equation, in isolation, can be fitted to data, but the `k` will necessarily be different if you use those equations for the same data. one equation is ***not*** the inverse of the other because the `r` are not the same. the paper isn't plain about this, glosses over the details. even the first answer given below doesn't discuss this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't promise that this is the most efficient way to apply the transform, but it is fully vectorised, and the interpolation is configurable. The coordinate space is pre-computed so that only the interpolation operation itself needs to be done once per frame.

```py
from typing import NamedTuple

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator


class Transform(NamedTuple):
    mn_high: tuple[int, int]
    interp_grid: tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]
    yxdistort: np.ndarray
    yxfixed: np.ndarray
    rect_axes: tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]

    @classmethod
    def setup(
        cls,
        dc: np.ndarray,
        k: float,
        mn: tuple[int, int],
        scale: float,
    ) -> 'Transform':
        ylong = np.arange(0, mn[0], scale)
        xlong = np.arange(0, mn[1], scale)
        yxrect_d3 = np.stack(
            np.meshgrid(xlong, ylong), axis=-1,
        )
        yxrect = yxrect_d3.reshape((-1, 2))[:, ::-1]

        interp_grid = tuple(
            dim.ravel()
            for dim in np.indices(dimensions=mn, sparse=True)
        )

        return cls(
            mn_high=yxrect_d3.shape[:2],
            interp_grid=interp_grid,
            yxdistort=redistort(dc=dc, k=k, vu=yxrect),
            yxfixed=undistort(dc=dc, k=k, yx=yxrect),
            rect_axes=(ylong, xlong),
        )

    def distort_image(self, image: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        distort_interp = RegularGridInterpolator(
            points=self.interp_grid, values=image, bounds_error=False,
        )
        return distort_interp(self.yxdistort).reshape(
            (*self.mn_high, -1)
        )

    def undistort_image(self, image: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        undistort_interp = RegularGridInterpolator(
            points=self.rect_axes, values=image, bounds_error=False,
        )
        return undistort_interp(self.yxfixed).reshape(
            (*self.mn_high, -1)
        )


def undistort(
    dc: np.ndarray,  # centre point, *2
    k: float,        # distort parameter aka. lambda
    yx: np.ndarray,  # distorted, n * 2
) -> np.ndarray:     # n * 2
    r2 = ((yx - dc)**2).sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)
    vu = dc + (yx - dc)/(1 + k*r2)
    return vu


def redistort(
    dc: np.ndarray,  # centre point, *2
    k: float,        # distort parameter aka. lambda
    vu: np.ndarray,  # non-distorted, n * 2
) -> np.ndarray:     # n * 2
    inner = k*((vu - dc)**2).sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)

    return (
        k*(
            dc*(
                + (vu**2).sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)
                - 2*dc*vu
                + dc**2
                + dc[::-1]**2
            )
            - 2*dc.prod()*vu[:, ::-1]
        )
        + 0.5*(vu - dc)*(
            1 - np.sqrt(1 - 4*inner)
        )
    )/inner


def regression_test() -> None:
    dcx = 320/2
    dcy = 240/2
    xd = 5
    yd = 17
    lambd = 1e-6

    r2 = (dcx - xd)**2 + (dcy - yd)**2
    xu = dcx + (xd - dcx)/(1 + lambd*r2)
    yu = dcy + (yd - dcy)/(1 + lambd*r2)

    dc = np.array((dcy, dcx))
    actual = undistort(
        dc=dc, k=lambd, yx=np.array((
            (yd, xd),
        )),
    )
    assert np.allclose(actual, (yu, xu))

    vu = np.array((
        (yu, xu),
        (40, 30),
        (25, 20),
    ))
    expected = np.array((
        (         yd,          xd),
        (38.04372287, 26.82104966),
        (22.11282237, 15.74521192),
    ))
    actual = redistort(dc, lambd, vu)
    assert np.allclose(expected, actual, rtol=0, atol=1e-8)


def estimate_resolution_loss(
    mn: tuple[int, int],
    dc: np.ndarray,
    k: float,
) -> float:
    # Pretty bad! This is not efficient.
    n = 200
    middle_strip = np.empty((n, 2))
    middle_strip[:, 0] = np.linspace(0, mn[0]-1, n)
    middle_strip[:, 1] = mn[1]/2

    distorted = redistort(dc=dc, k=k, vu=middle_strip)
    y, x = distorted.T
    y = y[np.isfinite(y)]

    res_reduce = mn[0]/(y.max() - y.min())
    return res_reduce


def roundtrip_demo(filename: str) -> None:
    # Once per parameter+resolution set
    imorig = np.array(Image.open(filename))
    mn = imorig.shape[:2]
    dc = 0.5*np.array(mn) + 0.1  # avoid a divide-by-zero
    k = 1e-6
    res_reduce = estimate_resolution_loss(mn=mn, dc=dc, k=k)
    transform = Transform.setup(mn=mn, dc=dc, k=k, scale=res_reduce)

    # Once every frame
    imdistort = transform.distort_image(imorig/255)
    imfixed = transform.undistort_image(imdistort)

    fig, (ax_orig, ax_distort, ax_fixed) = plt.subplots(ncols=3)
    ax_orig.imshow(imorig)
    ax_distort.imshow(imdistort)
    ax_fixed.imshow(imfixed)
    ax_orig.set_title('Original')
    ax_distort.set_title('Distorted')
    ax_fixed.set_title('Corrected')
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    regression_test()
    roundtrip_demo('baby goat.jpg')
```

[image: goats]

More can be done to handle the edge better, etc.

Answer (score 1):

To apply a per-pixel defined warp to multiple images, you can use `cv::remap()`. It's a function in the OpenCV library, so you might have encountered it already.

It takes a lookup table/matrix/map. This map defines, for each output pixel, the coordinates to sample in the input image. This is a "pull" transform. It allows interpolation. Since the operation of this implicitly inverts the transform represented in the map array, the transform itself has to be inverted from the normal sense (so they cancel). To reiterate: you have to consider, for each destination pixel, where to pull it from in the source image.

The opposite is called "push", which scatters each source pixel into the result image. Given source vertices (not pixels), that's the natural thing to do, but not for pixels. This scattering makes interpolation impossible (well, extremely hard and pointlessly wasteful to do), and so it leaves gaps all over the place unless the transform is a mere translation or shrinking the image. Any stretching, rotation, ... will leave gaps. That is why only novices even think to try that.

The map needs to have type `CV_32FC2` (simplest case), which is `(H, W, 2)` and dtype `float32` in numpy.

For prototyping, you can just set each element with a double for loop. It'll be slow but if you use **numba** and apply `@nb.njit()` to that function, it'll be fast again.

There are other flavors of map supported by `remap()`. You can split the floating point map into two individual planes, one for X lookup and one for Y lookup. There's also a fixed point (integer) arithmetic version that splits the floating point sampling coordinates into their integer parts and quantized floating point fractions formatted as indices into internal interpolation lookup tables (one per interpolation method). There's a function to convert maps. You can try it if you think that remap() on a `32FC2` map is too slow for your application.

Comment: So to implement this pull transform. I would need to build a map of size (inputH, inputW, 2), then invert my current get_undistorted() function to solve for the pixel position in the distorted image? So while looping through the double for loop I would calculate for a given output pixel, which pixel to sample from in the input distorted image.

Comment: I hope you meant `(outputH, outputW, 2)`, and yes, you'd need to invert your get_undistorted(). that would be ok to do numerically, unless an algebraic solution is feasible. it's what OpenCV does with the lens distortion model when undistorting individual points (I think, docs will say). all that effort does pay off because `remap()` is just a "graphics primitive", i.e. executes very efficiently, and in parallel. in the right circumstances (using UMat) it will probably even use an available GPU.

Comment: Sorry, yes I meant output. I’m a bit confused regarding the inversion step of the one-parameter model. I found this answer to a similar question “… only for the case of single-parameter pure radial distortion, i.e. when the only nonzero distortion parameter is k1, the coefficient of r^2. In this case the model inversion equation reduces to a cubic equation in r, and you can then express the inverse model using Cardano's formula…” (https://stackoverflow.com/a/67024171/23259743) could you expand a bit on how a solution can be obtained, or could you provide me with a resource on the topic?

Comment: n.b. my answer already has an analytic solution for the inverted (redistortion) function.

Comment: I don't have any resources nor do I have the math handy or validated. I think this result from wolfram alpha might help you invert the model: [WA link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+u+%3D+d+%2F+%281+%2B+k+*+d%5E2%29+for+d) (d is r_d and u is r_u)

Comment: it's not as simple as treating the distorted radius to be equal to the undistorted radius. I wouldn't say that's a proper analytic solution.